# Package in Sql Server agent job fails while in Integration Services Catalogs succeeds

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm facing some weird problem. I have a package which I made in SSIS, the package executes successfully from SSIS.

Deployed the solution into Integration Services Catalogs, Validated and executed the package successfully too, but when I create a new job in the SQL server agent and trying to start this package I keep getting the same error

> ORA 12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect...

BTW This connection manager works well in other jobs that I execute.
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S the error [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnYLD.png)

Comment: Does your proxy_name  have rights to access the database? If you've not specified any proxy_name name the service account is used.. WHen you run the package in the Integration Services Catalogs it is executed as "you" which indicates it might have something to do with rights...

Comment: I have full rights, I log as Admin...

Comment: You didn't read what i wrote. You may have full rights and this may be the reason you're confused that it doesn't work. Your service account / proxy name might not have the same access. Can you script out the agent job and post the code please ?

Comment: Added, I hope it is what you asked

Comment: Yes. Have you tried executing the package in 32-bit? I have some slight memory that some Oracle Drivers needs to be run in 32- bit.

Comment: Where can I check to if it is 32/64?

Comment: Check the 32-bit box and try to run the job again. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/06/12/use-32bit-runtime-option-for-sql-agent/

Comment: It worked! Thank you sir!

Comment: no problem. Please mark my answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the package as 32-bit since the Oracle driver you've installed is in 32-bit. Go to edit package step and simply check the Run as 32-bit checkbox.

[image]